# Stop output printing multiple times if function activated more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm activating a javascript function with a Jquery onclick button:

```
$('#on').click(function() {

var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  a[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    var text = document.createTextNode(this.innerHTML + " ");
    span.appendChild(text);
    document.getElementsByClassName('output')[0].appendChild(span);
  })
}
    });
```

The problem is if the button is clicked more than once the function will repeat more than once. In this case it will print the output multiple times. How can I modify the javascript function to only print one character per click?

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/874Ljaq1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery `.data()` function to set a flag when the button has been clicked once, and only proceed if the flag is not set.

The code:

```
$('#on').click(function () {
    // if we have a flag that indicates this button has been clicked before,
    // don't do anything.
    if ($(this).data('clicked')) 
        return;
    $(this).data('clicked', true); // set the flag
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            var span = document.createElement('span');
            var text = document.createTextNode(this.innerHTML + " ");
            span.appendChild(text);
            document.getElementsByClassName('output')[0].appendChild(span);
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the jQuery event binding method `one`

```
$('#on').one("click", function() {

    var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            var span = document.createElement('span');
            var text = document.createTextNode(this.innerHTML + " ");
            span.appendChild(text);
            document.getElementsByClassName('output')[0].appendChild(span);
        })
   }
});
```